# How to get redirect chain with selenium if I must directly click on banners and open it on another tab?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, redirect, har

I am working on a project, in which I should click banners and get redirect chains.

In order not to get my page override and to make it easier for next step, I thought I should `ctrl+click` on banners and make it open in another browser tab to get **all** the **real** redirect chains.

I've researched a lot, but only found that present methods would dump HAR files to get redirect chains. But to get HAR files, the **Network panel** in **Developer Tools window** should be opened previously in a tab. BUT, in my case, a new tab could not open a **Network panel** before the tab is loaded; I can't open the **Network panel** and reload the page either because redirect chains would not be real. Additionally, the embedded **performance log** is not appliable in my case

Can anyone tell me how can I solve these problems? Or was I wrong about any part above? Any advice would be greatly appreciated since I really have been working on it for long.

Comment: This sounds like it can be solved with [selenium-wire](https://pypi.org/project/selenium-wire/#response-objects) or with [browsermob](https://pypi.org/project/browsermob-proxy/)

Comment: Now working on selenium-wire. Browsermob can download HAR file, don't know whether I should open Network panel at first to do that for now.

Comment: selenium-wire seems ok, now working on the speed of it. Also, how to sift out real direct paths remains to be a question. By the way, in selenium-wire you can boot up an undetected-chrome which can pass by bot detection.

Comment: Regarding Browsermob I don't think you need the Network panel open...
Regarding selenium-wire, I think it's a great package! one of the advantages is collaboration with undetected-chrome.

Comment: But seems undetected-chrome isn't compatible with `click` method. See **important note** in [undetected-chormedriver](https://pypi.org/project/undetected-chromedriver/)

Comment: it works well with your comment. Consider write it as an answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the redirect chains, you'll need the HAR files.

There are a few packages that combine selenium with other libraries to accomplish this (and other additions as well).

One is [browsermob-proxy](https://browsermob-proxy-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

> BrowserMob Proxy allows you to manipulate HTTP requests and responses, capture HTTP content, and export performance data as a HAR file. BMP works well as a standalone proxy server, but it is especially useful when embedded in Selenium tests.

Here is an example:

```
from browsermobproxy import Server
server = Server("path/to/browsermob-proxy")
server.start()
proxy = server.create_proxy()

from selenium import webdriver

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--proxy-server={0}".format(proxy.proxy)) #Configure chrome options
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
proxy.new_har("StackOverFlow") 
driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com")
print(proxy.har)
```

There are other libraries such as [selenium-wire](https://pypi.org/project/selenium-wire/) that have similar capabilities (with other features as well).

Note: no need to open the Network panel.

Make sure to [download the proxy](https://bmp.lightbody.net/) and add the path to the initiation of the Server.